# How can I automatically change my desktop background every day?

Tags: python, linux, image

I am interested in having my desktop background automatically change every day. Perhaps taking the "picture of the day" from some website.

Is this something I could do with a Python script? I can code pretty well but I only really do numerical work, so I'm just looking for an overview of the process and then I can figure out the details.

I imagine it's fairly simple to have my script visit the website I'm interested in and to download the image. But then how do I engage with my (Linux) OS to tell it to set the image as background?

Thanks.

Comment: what desktop environment/window manager? I think you just need to make script to change wallpaper from command line (e.g.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity ), then add it to crontab

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268791/how-to-change-the-desktop-wallpaper-on-linux-from-within-a-shell-bash-script or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59653/change-desktop-wallpaper-from-terminal -- this is not really Python specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*But then how do I engage with my (Linux) OS to tell it to set the image as background?*

This might depend on what exactly system are using, but after quick search I found [danilodellaquila.com article](https://danilodellaquila.com/en/blog/how-to-automatically-change-your-desktop-background-wallpaper) about doing that in **Ubuntu**. Check if any of two following commands do work after replacing path to some jpg image existing in your machine

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///path/to/wallpaper.jpg"
```

or

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename /path/to/wallpaper.jpg
```